# Jenkins sonar report generation failed

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, report

I have been facing an issue with the java report generation job in Jenkins. Most of my jobs are falling for the same reason. Even though these all are getting failed it managed to produce reports but I want to get rid of this issue so my Jenkins job as well getting success.

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 7:29.991s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue May 04 22:46:55 CDT 2021
[INFO] Final Memory: 91M/679M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot change build result while in COMPLETED -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot change build result while in COMPLETED
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.BuilderCommon.handleBuildError(BuilderCommon.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven3Launcher.main(Maven3Launcher.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main.launch(Maven3Main.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot change build result while in COMPLETED
    at hudson.model.Run.setResult(Run.java:459)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuild$ProxyImpl.setResult(MavenBuild.java:494)
    at hudson.maven.MavenBuild$ProxyImpl2.setResult(MavenBuild.java:547)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.model.Executor$2.call(Executor.java:895)
    at hudson.util.InterceptingProxy$1.invoke(InterceptingProxy.java:23)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.setResult(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor49407.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:608)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:583)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:542)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
```

[my jenkins configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0lOt.png)

Report generation command

```
clean verify org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar -Dsonar.branch=Platform7.3
```

Comment: What is the actual build failure (above the FAILURE in the first line you posted), what maven plugin / step was run? Also, maven 3.0.3 is not a great choice. Go 3.0.5 or 3.6.3.

Comment: Really using such nine year old Maven version furthermore the [sonar plugin is very old as well](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.9.0.2155/maven-plugin) you have to upgrade your environment. You are using extreme old software which results in issues which are solved years ... First upgrade to most recent version of Maven (3.8.1) etc.